# Unable to Enable/Desable a control

Tags: xml, controls, office-js

I am using  : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/dev/add-ins/design/disable-add-in-commands.

With Visual studio 19, when inserting in the XML the 'Enabled'element in the right place, I get an "invalid children element" warning.

With VSC I can insert these elements, and I can make the control appear ou fade manualy (i.e. writing the 'Enabled' parameter to false or true and running the code), but on the following step, for the RibbonUpdateData block (the snippet from microsoft doc) I get a "property 'ribbon' doesn't exist on type 'type of office'" warning

Comment: Please show the code that generates the "property 'ribbon' doesn't exist on type 'type of office'" warning. Also, what is your Office version and build number?

Answer (score 0):

@ Rick Kirkham : Excel Version number is : 2104 (Build 13929 20296)

Here is a view of the code (it's a copy paste from microsoft doc)
[office.ribbon call snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujPxB.png)

Comment: Don't create an answer to your question. Instead edit the original question.

Answer (score 0):

For the Visual Studio issue, Visual Studio may be using an out-of-date manifest schema. Try this:

1. On your development machine, locate the existing `TaskPaneAppVersionOverridesV1_0.xsd`. This should be located in your Visual Studio installation directory under `./Xml/Schemas/{lcid}`. For example, on a typical installation of VS 2019 32-bit on an English (US) system, the full path would be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Xml\Schemas\1033`.
2. Rename the existing file to `TaskPaneAppVersionOverridesV1_0.old`.
3. Copy the contents of the XSD file at [this URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-owemxml/82e93ec5-de22-42a8-86e3-353c8336aa40) to a new file named `TaskPaneAppVersionOverridesV1_0.xsd` and put it where the old one is.
4. Restart Visual Studio and try again.

Comment: Thanks Rick. I’ll try & tell you

Comment: This did solve the visual studio 2019 issue as far as Xml is concerned. Thanks. However I still have for the ts part the Office.ribbon  warning  : 'ribbon' doesn't exist on type 'type of office' and I am still unable to enable or disable a control

Comment: note that the new XSD files raises many useless warnings saying 'complextype 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrdes: host' already declared